# Why isn't my implementation of the A* search algorithm working?

Tags: c++, algorithm, a-star

I'm trying to find the shortest path from the top-left corner to the bottom-right corner of an `N*N` grid. I have already coded a breadth-first search solution for this, but I'm wondering if I can improve the runtime of my algorithm by using the A* search algorithm instead.

My code for the A* search algorithm is below:

```
int H(int item, int end, int N){ // heuristic function: euclidean distance from item to exit
    return ((item/N-end/N)*(item/N-end/N) + (item%N-end%N)*(item%N-end%N));
}

int Astar(int start, int end, const vector <vector<int>> &adj, int N){
    vector <bool> visited(adj.size(), false);
    vector <int> dist(adj.size(), INF);
    priority_queue <pi, vector<pi>, greater<pi>> Q;

    Q.push({0, start});
    dist[0] = 0;

    while(!Q.empty()){
        int curr = Q.top().second;
        Q.pop();

        if(visited[curr]){continue;}
        visited[curr] = true;

        if(curr == end){break;}

        for(int item : adj[curr]){
            if(dist[curr] + 1 < dist[item]){
                dist[item] = dist[curr] + 1;
                Q.push({dist[item] + H(item), item});
            }
        }
    }

    print(visited, N);

    return dist[end];
}
```

However, my implementation doesn't seem to work. I'm confused, because the A* search algorithm is described as almost exactly the same as Dijkstra's algorithm, except with a heuristic function added in the priority queue. Here is a case where my above implementation fails to find the shortest path:

```
S.........
..........
..........
...#######
...#......
..##.###..
.....#.#..
..####....
.....#....
..####..#E

# are obstacles
S is the start and E is the end
Can move up, down, left, or right only

The answer should be 22 but my function returns 24
```

Note that in my code, I represent each square as a single integer instead of a pair of integers, by mapping each (x, y) coordinate to (x*N + y), where N is the height and width of the grid.

So, my question is, am I misunderstanding the A* search algorithm in my code? Can somebody please tell me how to change my code so that it produces the correct output?

Comment: Consider the effect of the `visited[curr]` check when a revisit has a lower cost than the original visit.

Comment: You only call `H` with one argument when it has three.

Comment: Why are you calling H with only one arg? 3 args expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is not working because your heuristic does not match up with the movement options you have. Specifically, your heuristic is an Euclidean distance heuristic while movement is restricted to Up, Down, Left, and Right only.

In other words, your heuristic is admissible, but not consistent. This means that it does not guarantee that the first visit of the destination returns an optimal path. To guarantee this, you need a consistent heuristic such as the Manhattan Distance.

[Wikipedia Admissible Heuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic)

[Wikipedia Consistent Heuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic)

The key takeaway from the above two articles is that your heuristic should (A) be admissible, or always underestimate the actual cost (which your Euclidean distance heuristic does) and (B) be consistent, meaning that its estimate is always <= (the estimated distance from a neighouring vertex + the cost of reaching that vertex). The Euclidean distance heuristic does *not* satisfy (B). The Manhattan Distance (minimum possible way to reach the goal with only Up, Down, Left, and Right assuming no obstacles), however, fits these two requirement perfectly.